# PhoneGap - saving data to local file system (File API)

Tags: android, file, cordova, save

I just started to play with [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) of PhoneGap and already have some problems with saving process. Here is the javascript code:

```
function saveCourseToFile() {
    console.log("checkpoint 1");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
}
function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log("checkpoint 2");
    console.log("Opened file system: " + fileSystem.name);
    fileSystem.root.getFile("course.oerk", {create:true, exclusive:false}, gotFileEntry, onFSError);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("checkpoint 3");
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSError);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
    console.log("checkpoint 4: write success!");
    };
    writer.write("test test test");
}
function onFSError(err) {
    console.log(err.code);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
</script>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="page1">
        <a href="#page2">Click me</a>
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            saveCourseToFile();
        </script>
        <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

But in the device file system no such file (course.oerk) as a result. Here is a piece of logcat:

```
02-18 22:36:55.542: D/Cordova(746): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html#coursesPage)
02-18 22:36:55.542: D/Cordova(746): Trying to fire onNativeReady
02-18 22:36:55.552: D/DroidGap(746): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
02-18 22:36:55.552: D/DroidGap(746): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#coursesPage)
02-18 22:36:56.223: I/Choreographer(746): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you waiting until you get the "deviceready" event?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald my onDeviceReady includes in `<body>` tag and I'm trying to call `saveCourseToFile()` after moving to the particular `<div>` tag. See code **update** for details.

Comment: Okay, but what is your error? There is nothing in logcat to show that saveCourseToFile was even called.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald here is the full version of LogCat:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/logcat.txt
I'm also suprising that logcat don't have even my scheckpoints.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald now I fixed it. Namely I just moved `saveCourseToFile();` to the anchor onclick="saveCourseToFile()". Thanks for the contribution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Just by moving the `saveCourseToFile();` to the anchor:

```
....
<div id="page1">
    <a href="#page2" onclick="saveCourseToFile()">Click me</a>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <p>Text text text text</p>
</div>
....
```